# How to assign a value inside a (mouseover) in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I have want show a value (which it is the return of a function in the component.ts) only when the mouse pointer is over the button.

I want to do something like this.

```
<div class="dropdown mat-container" style=" margin-left: 2%;">
    <button class="dropbtn" (mouseover)= "myVariable = haveRoutes(template._id)">Tipo</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content btn btn-primary">
        <a>{{myVariable}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The function in the component.ts

```
haveRoutes(id){
    this._ApprovalsService.getQuantityByTemplate(id).subscribe(
      (quantity:any) => {
        if(quantity.count == 0){
          return  "Draft"
        }else{
          return "Not draft"
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

One solution for now, is store the value in the model and change it in the component.ts like this:

```
export class GetComponent implements OnInit {
     message = "";
     
     //some other functions

     haveRoutes(id){
        this._ApprovalsService.getQuantityByTemplate(id).subscribe(
          (quantity:any) => {
            if(quantity.count == 0){
              this.message = "Draft"
            }else{
              this.message = "Not Draft"
            }
          } 
      );
  }
```

And in the html.

```
<div class="dropdown mat-container" style=" margin-left: 2%;margin-right: 4%">
    <button class="dropbtn" (mouseover)= "haveRoutes(template._id)">Tipo</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content btn btn-primary">
            <a>{{message}}</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

It works but it's slower, so I want to try like the first way hopping to get the value quickly.

Comment: I would go with the 2nd solution. It is slow because it is related to an API call, so the only way to speed it up is to either make the call once and cache it or deal with its slowness

Answer (score 1):

You could consider PRE-storing the values in the component, something like this pseudo-code:

component:

```
quantitiesDictionary:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
quantitiesDictionary.push(id, this._ApprovalsService.getQuantityByTemplate(id));
```

template:

```
{{ quantitiesDictionary[id].count == 0 ? 'Draft' : 'Not Draft' }}
```